# strange epoch date number issue

Tags: c#, date, unix-timestamp, alternate

I'm working with an data set in which there is a date field with dates that look like the following:

> 42437.4261290278
>   42437.5460402431
>   42437.5478825116

with the larger of the numbers being the most recent. One of us believes it is relating to unix epoch and alternate time representations. The issue we are facing now is reading those date's above into standard MM-DD-YYYY format. Any one have any ideas on how to convert these alternate date forms into standard dates?

I'm trying to do this in C#. And for reference, I expect that the last two dates listed to be sometime on March 8th, 2016 and the first to be some time before then.

Comment: You might want to indicate where the data set came from. Is it from another application, a database or spreadsheet? Best guess is it is a number of whole and fractional days since some baseline, but without knowing the base date or units, conversion will be a guess. 42437 days ago is somewhere around 1900 or 1901.

Comment: I think IBM's might use a baseline of 1900-01-01 for some date calculations...

Comment: This is from an Oracle Database. Really the only info i have access to are the numbers themselves.

Comment: How do you get the values from the database? What is the type of the column that the values come from?

Comment: the type of the column is an Oracle Number

Comment: @RunFranks525 1) Are you absolutely sure about what you think those dates should be? When a datetime is stored as a floating-point number, it is usual to store the days since an epoch as the integer part and the fraction of the day as the fractional part. Which suggests all your examples are on the same day. 2) Do you have any way to find the code that stores those values and try to figure out what is going on?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am sure that the 2nd and 3rd dates are on the 8th, the first very well could be on the 8th as well, but just before the 2nd and 3rd. Unfortunately this data is entered through other software so we don't see how the it is actually entered.

Comment: @RunFranks525 Can you make sure that the system which is entering the dates has its system date set correctly and somehow force it to create an entry which will represent today? And note the time. It is most peculiar that it appears to be days since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and yet you say it was two days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your assertion that the dates represented are 2016-03-08, I assume the start of the epoch is 1899-12-30:

```
static string UnixTimeStampToDateAsString(double ts)
{
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
    DateTime d = epoch.AddDays(ts);
    return (d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (double dateNumber in new double[] { 42437.4261290278, 42437.5460402431, 42437.5478825116 })
    {
        Console.WriteLine(UnixTimeStampToDateAsString(dateNumber));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Outputs:

> 2016-03-08 10:13:37
>   2016-03-08 13:06:17
>   2016-03-08 13:08:57

I have to state that the 30th of December 1899 is a rather unlikely value, but I suppose someone might have had a "reason" to use that.

**Edit** Thanks to @EricLippert I can suggest this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(dateNumber).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: In fact, not only is there a reason, the founder of this site can tell you what that reason is. See my answer.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks! That reminded me of the OADate functions. Did you, or Joel, happen to write the `DateTime.FromOADate` method? I see that Raymond Chen says to use them in the article linked from yours.

Comment: I did not. I wrote that function in the JScript runtime though, and much of the VBScript date library. Good times. Joel left MSFT in 1994 and I never met him when I was an intern.

Answer (score 7):

These are OLE Automation VT_DATE values. This is the date system used by Microsoft products such as Excel and pre-.NET versions of Visual Basic.  It is a somewhat bizarre date format.

The format is: consider the double to have two parts: a signed integer and an unsigned fraction. The signed integer is the number of days since 30 Dec 1899.  Note NOT 31 Dec 1899 and NOT 1 Jan 1900. The fraction is the fraction of the 24 hour (always!) day gone by. No adjustment is made for the 23 or 25 hour days we have twice a year.

This format has an interesting (to me) history; you can read about it in my blog article from 2003:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/16/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date/

And Stack Overflow founder Joel Spolsky's article from 2006:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Note that if you have *negative* VT_DATE values then you must be very careful to get the conversion correct.  The code is not hard; it's just a couple lines, but you have to reason about it carefully. I used to ask "take the difference between two VT_DATEs" as an interview question, and a surprising number of candidates cannot actually do subtraction.

Comment: People might hate you in the distant future for all your admissions :D Clever people wont though :)

Comment: OT: I wish you would be more active on C# discussions on Github though, if just for historical insight. You know more than most in that domain.

Comment: @leppie: I've been meaning to do so. Not enough hours in the day!

Comment: @Eric: I missed the fact that the last two timestamps in the question are supposed to represent March 8th.. So you were right, it can't be the NTP epoch (January 1, 1900), i deleted my answer.