# java from double epoch to date time

Tags: java, date, parsing, time

How to parse date time from double to datetime in java? In c# it is ok from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924473/strange-epoch-date-number-issue)

Suggest for parsing in java?

Example:

```
    44233.8647553819// --> date: 2021-02-06 20:45:14
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java convert double to date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666270/java-convert-double-to-date-format)

Comment: The same approach from the accepted answer to the linked question works here too.

Comment: @zappee double to date is ok, but hours and minute and seconds?  Are lose with this approach

Comment: @FreeBird ok some approach, but in java there isn't method to add double and information about hours, minute,seconds are lose

Comment: @BasilBourque this answer is accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35929138/642319

Comment: @FreeBird I was referring to the duplicate [linked by zappee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666270/java-convert-double-to-date-format) while you were referring to the link in the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, this mechanism of storing a time stamp is silly, and C# allows it by mixing up different conceptions of time. It does what you evidently want, but that's not a good thing - those kinds of APIs make it easy to make mistakes.

In java, the same API exists, but only allows you to specify an integral number of days - thus, you can't save your `.8647553819` part - you'd have to apply that directly.

But that's not possible without answering some more questions about where on the planet you are.

Let's start with just the days part:

```
double raw = 44233.8647553819;
long days = (long) raw;
double fraction = raw - days;

LocalDate epoch = LocalDate.of(1899, 12, 30);
LocalDate date = epoch.plusDays(days);
System.out.println(date);
> 2021-02-06 - so far, so good
```

Now turning `.8647553819` into a specific time is much more convoluted. What if that date is a day with only 23 hours? What if it has 25 hours? This representation system can't deal with any of this, and it also has issues with accuracy; doubles are optimized for accuracy and not speed. So, this is a best effort basis kinda deal

```
double maxSeconds = LocalTime.MAX.toSecondOfDay();
int seconds = (int) (maxSeconds * fraction);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(seconds);
LocalDateTime stamp = date.atTime(time);
System.out.println(stamp);
> 2021-02-06T20:45:14
```

I can't stress enough that this is a silly system, but, there you have it.

Comment: I have used methd in this class: https://github.com/cuba-platform/apache-poi/blob/master/poi/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.java